# How does Veracrypt proceed with small password?

Tags: aes, key, veracrypt

Veracrypt is a tool to encrypt disk.

It uses many encrypting algorithms, including AES.

I'm wondering if someone knows how Veracrypt proceed if we choose AES encryption with a password of 3 characters (considering that Veracrypt will use the password as the AES key, and the size key must be a fixed size, eg. 128, 192, 256 bits) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

veracrypt will not use the users password as the AES key. The AES key will generated from random numbers and protected by a header key. This header key is derived from the password using a [key derivation function (KDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) which both hides that the password is weak and also creates a key which is long enough. For more details see https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Header%20Key%20Derivation.

Of course, an attacker knowing that only a very weak password was used can brute-force it.

Comment: Can you confirm me that the result of the key derivation will be the "master key" ?

Comment: @DukeNukem: no, its the header key. For more details see https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Header%20Key%20Derivation. I've updated the answer.